# Assigning points in a lattice as "occupied"?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm attempting to write a program that simulates diffusion limited aggregation. I'm using a function that I previously wrote to generate pseudo-random numbers. I've now gotten to the point where I have some code that uses this generator to randomise a point on a circle on a square lattice. I've also added a bit of code to generate more particles that attach onto the initial nucleus on a random cardinal direction, again dictated by the previously written generator. Here's my code:

```
program snowflake
implicit none
integer, dimension(-25:25, -25:25) :: lattice
integer ::  x1, y1, r=4, N, i, S, E, W, x=0, y=0, l, j
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
real(kind=dp) ::  pi = 3.1415927, thet1, thet2, rn1, rn2, temp, var


do l = -25,25
    lattice(l,:) = 1 !occupied initial
end do

S = 1     !Initialising the size of the nucleus S = 1

open(unit=20, file="grid.dat", status="replace")

do i=1,5  !Generating the random positions for the particles

    x1 = r*lcg()
    y1 = r*lcg()

write(20, *) x1, y1
print *, x1, y1  
end do

do j=1, 50
var = lcg()
if (var <= .250) then
   y = y + 1

else if (var > 0.250 .and. var <= 0.500) then
   y = y - 1
else if (var > 0.500 .or. lcg() <= 0.750) then
   x = x + 1  
else if (var > 0.750 .or. lcg() <= 1.00) then
   x = x - 1
end if  
 S = S + 1        
print *, x, y, S, var
write(20, *) x, y

end do

contains

function lcg(seed)

  integer, optional, intent(in) :: seed
  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
  real(kind=dp) :: x = 0, lcg, A=100, B= 104001, M = 714025

  if(present(seed)) x = seed
  x = mod(A * x + B, M)
  lcg = x/714025

end function



end program
```

So the terminal shows that my lcg is printing out ok values, the size is right (?) and my x and y values are good. However, the bit I am stuck on is how to now assign the points that these "Particles" are in as "Occupied", as to stop other particles from attaching there also.
Any suggestions on code improvement is also welcomed, thank you!

(also, for now I'm plotting the x and y values to see the shape, in the future I plan to turn it into a pbm file)

Comment: There are a number of features of your code that I don't understand.  One is why all the locations in the lattice start as `occupied`.  I would have (based on a limited knowledge of the problem domain) expected the lattice to be empty at the start.  A second is that the code nowhere attempts to update any elements of `lattice` after they are all first set.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I wanted to set the coordinate 0,0 in the lattice to occupied at first, then update the lattice as particles are added, I'm assuming I've done this incorrectly then?

Comment: As I wrote before, ALL the lattice positions are set to `1` (in the first do loop), and NONE are later updated.  I'd expect to see a line such as `lattice(0,0) = 1` somewhere, and later `lattice(x,y) = 1` at appropriate places.

Comment: @timetabedlidalot I suggest that you break up the problem in smaller pieces. Currently, your code does not appear consistent and there are many comments on the code (access to data, overall logic, etc). Suggestion for subdivision: inialization of the variables, setting up the initial state, update step, etc.